# How to union a data set with a specific rule

Tags: sql, datetime, union, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, full-outer-join

I have two almost identical data sets that I am trying to union but I only want to union them if there isn't a date in File 1 for it already.

Data Set 1

| File | Date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2020 | a |
| 1 | 1/2/2020 | b |
| 1 | 1/3/2020 | c |

Data Set 2

| File | Date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1/1/2020 | a |
| 2 | 1/2/2020 | b |
| 2 | 1/3/2020 | c |
| 2 | 1/4/2020 | d |

Ideal output

| File | Date | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2020 | a |
| 1 | 1/2/2020 | b |
| 1 | 1/3/2020 | c |
| 2 | 1/4/2020 | d |

If both data sets have the same dates, then I only want to use data from File #1

```
SELECT FILE, DATE, TYPE FROM TABLE A
UNION
SELECT FILE, DATE, TYPE FROM TABLE B
```

[set up] https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/whfZGwnAJcAYaQii6avF6k/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all` with `not exists` as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FILE, DATE, TYPE FROM TABLEA
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT FILE, DATE, TYPE FROM TABLEB B
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM TABLEA A
  WHERE A.DATE = B.DATE
    AND A.TYPE = B.TYPE)
```

**Note**: I have used `distinct` to make the logic similar to union as it removes the duplicate. You can remove the `distinct` from your query if you do not have duplicates in your individual tables.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a `full join`. The answer by Popeye works and is a typical approach in databases that do not support the syntax. But [Snowflake does](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join.html), so the query is simpler and more efficiently phrased as:

```
select coalesce(t1.file, t2.file) as file, date, coalesce(t1.type, t2.type) as type
from t1
full outer join t2 using (date)
```

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this if there are 10+ columns or do I have to wrap coalesce around each column and alias?

Comment: @andaman: no, you need `coalesce()` for this.